# How to insert values when tables are linked by foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, foreign-keys

So I have four tables having the following fields

```
Student_Master
---------------------
Student id(Primary Key)
Student Name
Class Id
Document Upload
```

```
Student Marks
------------
Marks_Id
Student_Id(Foreign Key)
Subject_ID(Foreign Key)
Marks
```

```
Subject
-----------
Subject ID
Subject Name
```

```
Class
----------
Class ID
Class Name
```

And my form on the page has following fields:

```
Student Name
Class
Subject
Marks
Doc Upload
```

Now how do I insert the values into multiple tables and they have foreign key references in between them.The project is in ASP and I am using SQL Server

Comment: You must specify if the id's are automatically defined in the database, or if you create them

Comment: The Id's are all auto generate..

Answer (score 1):

```
First Try starting inserting the values from the parent table and then move to the secobdary tables.
Student_Master and Subject would be the parents to Student_Marks
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert them in the parent tables first, where the primary key is defined. After that, you can fill the child and unrelated tables as you please, as long as you conform to the constraints. Student_Master and Subject would be the parents to Student_Marks, from what I can tell.

If you're asking how to write from the form to a database, you have some researching to do. Look into ADO.NET and the classes/objects you'll need to accomplish this.

Whatever you do, don't piecemeal the SQL together (inline SQL) from user values. Use paramterized stored procedures.

Comment: My question is that when a user enters a particular class.How can I get to enter the class ID in the tables?

Comment: You can use databinding on your control or you can possibly use a tag to hold the id. It all depends on what you're using. To fill your control full of classes, you are getting that from the db, right? At that point, you can get the ids too. If the class names are unique, you can pass them into your stored procedure when saving everything and get your I'd then with a select ClassId from Class where ClassName = @className.

Comment: Look into databinding, though. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure which accepts parameters "Student Name, Class , Subject, Marks, Doc Upload". First insert data to table "Class", SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the last inserted ID value; insert the same into a variable and insert it to "Student_Master" table. Follow the same for other tables too. Query will look like:

```
Declare @Scope_Class INT
INSERT INTO Class ([Class Name]) VALUES ('Class 1')
SET @Scope_Class =SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Student_Master ([Student Name], [Class Id], [Document Upload]) VALUES ('Stud 1' , @Scope_Class, 'Doc 1')
```